# Solution for 1 D heat conduction with Finite Difference not reducing error with increase in grid points

Tags: c, numerical-methods, euclidean-distance, von-neumann

I am solving 1 D heat conduction equation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void grid(int nx, double xst, double xen, double *x, double *dx)
{
  int i;

  *dx = (xen-xst)/(double)(nx-1);

  for(i=0; i<nx; i++)
    x[i] = (double)i * (*dx); // ensure x[0] == 0.0 and x[nx-1] == 1.0
}

void get_exact_solution(int nx, double time, double *x, double *Texact)
{
// calculates exact solution
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<nx; i++)
    Texact[i] = erf((x[i]-0.5)/2.0/sqrt(time));
}


void enforce_bcs(int nx, double *x, double *T)
{
  T[0] = -1.0;
  T[nx-1] = 1.0;
}

void set_initial_condition(int nx, double *x, double *T)
{
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<nx; i++)
    T[i] = tanh((x[i]-0.5)/0.1);

  enforce_bcs(nx,x,T); //ensure BCs are satisfied at t = 0
}

void get_rhs(int nx, double dx, double *x, double *T, double *rhs)
{
  int i;
  double dxsq = dx*dx;

  // compute rhs. For this problem, d2T/dx2
  for(i=1; i<nx-1; i++)
    rhs[i] = (T[i+1]+T[i-1]-2.0*T[i])/dxsq;
}

void timestep_Euler(int nx, double dt, double dx, double *x, double *T, double *rhs)
{

  int i;

  // compute rhs
  get_rhs(nx,dx,x,T,rhs);

  // (Forward) Euler scheme
  for(i=1; i<nx-1; i++)
    T[i] = T[i] + dt*rhs[i];  // T^(it+1)[i] = T^(it)[i] + dt * rhs[i];

  // set Dirichlet BCs
  enforce_bcs(nx,x,T);

}

void output_soln(int nx, int it, double tcurr, double *x, double *T)
{
  int i;
  FILE* fp;
  char fname[100];

  sprintf(fname, "T_x_%04d.dat", it);
  //printf("\n%s\n", fname);

  fp = fopen(fname, "w");
  for(i=0; i<nx; i++)
    fprintf(fp, "%lf %lf\n", x[i], T[i]);
  fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{

  int nx;
  double *x, *T, *rhs, tst, ten, xst, xen, dx, dt, tcurr, *Texact;
  int i, it, num_time_steps, it_print;
  FILE* fp;  


  nx =10; //grid points

  xst = 0, //starting and ending in space
  xen = 1;
  tst=0; // start and end in time
  ten=1


  printf("Inputs are: %d %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", nx, xst, xen, tst, ten);

  x = (double *)malloc(nx*sizeof(double));
  T = (double *)malloc(nx*sizeof(double));
  Texact = (double *)malloc(nx*sizeof(double));
  rhs = (double *)malloc(nx*sizeof(double));


  grid(nx,xst,xen,x,&dx);         // initialize the grid

  set_initial_condition(nx,x,T);  // initial condition

  // prepare for time loop
  dt = 0.001; 

  num_time_steps = (int)((ten-tst)/dt) + 1; // why add 1 to this?
  it_print = num_time_steps/10;             // write out approximately 10 intermediate results

  // start time stepping loop
  for(it=0; it<num_time_steps; it++)
  {
    tcurr = tst + (double)it * dt;

    timestep_Euler(nx,dt,dx,x,T,rhs);    // update T

    // output soln every it_print time steps
    //if(it%it_print==0)
      //output_soln(nx,it,tcurr,x,T);
  }

  get_exact_solution( nx, ten, x, Texact);

  int loop;
  double sq_diff,total,err;
  total = 0;

  for(loop = 0; loop < nx; loop++)
      printf("%f ", T[loop]);

  printf("\n");

  for(loop = 0; loop < nx; loop++)
      printf("%f ", Texact[loop]);

  for(loop = 0; loop < nx; loop++){
      sq_diff = (T[loop] - Texact[loop])*(T[loop] - Texact[loop]);
      total = total+sq_diff;
    }

  err = sqrt(total);
  printf("\n L2 Norm error = %f",err);


  printf("\n");
  free(rhs);
  free(T);
  free(x);

  return 0;
}
```

Ideally, increasing number of grid point (`nx` in the program) should decrease the Error that I have calculated on final Time `ten` using exact solution `Texact` and numerical solution `T`.

The error should  decrease with small increase in `nx` till the solution is stable and follows stability criteria (Von Neumann stability criteria.). But in my case this is not happening and error is increasing with increase in `nx`.

I am calculating the L2_norm error between `T` and `Texact`. 
`Texact` is calculated by the function `get_exact_solution`.

[This plot shows the problem for different cases.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IgtQ.png)

Please help in correcting this program.

Comment: is this c or c++ ?  please only tag the language you are actually telling your compiler to compile this as

Comment: it is C code. Sorry I have also tagged C++

Comment: @idclev463035818 Here, the problem is in the algorithm, which is 99.44% c/c++ agnostic. So, the dual tag is _appropriate_.

Comment: @CraigEstey I disagree, because if this is tagged as C++ one could discuss why there is `malloc`, `free` and other stuff one should not use in C++. Tagging only C gets that out of the way. If it really is language agnostic I'd rather also remove the C tag, but without close inspection I am not sure if the problem is not in the code. Feel free to revert, if you think different, though I stand by my decision

Comment: Are you sure about the exact solution? As a first look the algorithm seems ok

Comment: If you run it long enough do you get a straight line? (as the equilibrium solution is)

Comment: Yes its working fine but it is taking more iterations when I increase NX value. For the same number of iteration it is giving more error when Nx is large